# $.ajax in wordpress - Slow and not caching

Tags: ajax, performance, wordpress, caching, response

I'm having troubles with a script, related to wordpress and ajax.. I think it loads really slow, and if I click a clicked link, it takes the exact same time (not caching)

What I'm doing is, loading single.php in other page. Each time a link-post is clicked, that post is loaded through Ajax inside a div.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        'url':post_link,
        'type':'POST',
        'beforeSend': function(){
            jQuery(".container").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
        },
        'success':function(results){
            // some functions
        }
});
```

Any ideas what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP POST** instructions aren't cached; you need to use **HTTP GET/HEAD** if you want caching to occur.

As for why it's "slow", the information you've given isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard...

do you mean I should use " 'type':'GET', " instead? Because I tried that but it's the same..
about the 'slow part' question, single.php loads only a title, content (a couple of text lines), and gallery shortcode.. I don't think is too much data. (what info do you need?)

Comment: Where is it loading the "Title" and "Content" from? A MySQL database? 
How long does it take to load the URL directly in your browser?

Comment: That info comes from the wordpress database.. its a post..
I've done what you just told me, and directly into the browser it takes almost the same time.. 
I guess it doesn't have a solution but making wordpress run faster..

Comment: Yeah, definitely doesn't sound like an AJAX problem. If you post the source code of the resource you're requesting then we might be able to improve performance, but it could equally be a server/database issue that would need tracing on the server. Sorry I can't be of more help at this time :/